# Chrome loading same resources from memory cache and from disk cache - intermittent

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, caching

I've noticed that our sites cached js resources are sometimes loaded twice from the cache.  Chrome will retrieve the resource from memory but then also go to the disk to retrieve the same resource.  The Response Headers of both items are identical.  The Request Header can vary but I don't see any kind of a pattern.  This only seems to be an issue in Chrome.  I've not noted the behaviour in Firefox.

I've disabled all my Chrome extensions and still see the issue.  I also see the issue on both my local environment and on our Test Servers.  I've compared the duplicate files and they are identical.

It only appears to be an issue with our js resources.

An example of a duplicated resources Response Header (same for both):

```
Accept-Ranges:bytes
Cache-Control:public,max-age=604800
Content-Length:3277768
Content-Type:application/javascript
Date:Tue, 30 Jan 2018 10:25:22 GMT
ETag:"3697cc18996d31:0"
Last-Modified:Fri, 26 Jan 2018 09:40:52 GMT
Server:Microsoft-IIS/10.0
```

General:

```
Request URL:http://dev.localsite.com/dist/app.bundle-cc0bc51ac1c5549dc59f.js
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK (from memory cache) --this indicates from disk cache on disk version
Remote Address:127.0.0.1:80
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

The Request Header is different but again it does vary.  Two identical resources loaded have the following Request Headers:

Version 1 (from memory):

```
Request Headers
Provisional headers are shown
```

Version 2 (from disk):

```
Request Headers
Provisional headers are shown
Referer:http://dev.localsite.com/madeUpPage
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.132 Safari/537.36
```

Has anyone had or seen this behavior before and can anyone explain it!?

[Example duplicate JS resource as viewed in Network tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yTEwv.jpg)

Comment: Hello, did you find a solution to this problem?

Comment: Hi SRINI794 - sorry for the late reply.  No unfortunately, I didn't get to the bottom of this and got pulled onto something else.